# Why is Internet Explorer 11 Garbage Collection taking so long?

Tags: internet-explorer, garbage-collection, internet-explorer-11

I have a page on a website for some reason this particular page is the same as others however in Internet Explorer 11 it has a long running script error. With further investigation I find that it is because it is doing garbage collection.

Why is it taking so long for garbage collection? How can I stop this from slowing down my application?

In chrome its smooth as butter and works fast.

Here is the profiler showing it took over 73 seconds just for GC.[image]